# how to create keyboard app extension in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui

I am new to swiftUI.I need to create a keyboard extension in swiftui. I just can't find out how to do that. I am searching on internet for whole day but still can't find out how to do that.
Here is some code that I wrote :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           
            keyboard()
        }
        
    }
}

struct keyboard: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIInputViewController {
        let inputVC = UIInputViewController()
        return inputVC
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIInputViewController, context: Context) {
        print("some text")
    }
     
}
```

The above code is written in extension folder's keyboardViewController.swift file and not giving me any kind of keyboard display.

IF I write UIKit UIInputController (the file created itself when we create an extension) code in same file then only I can see a keyboard extension appearing.

I want to design keyboard in UIKit Inputviewcontroller type of class and then display it using UIViewControllerRepresentable in swiftui contentview.

Now my question is-> Is this Approach right?? IF yes then please guide me ahead. IF no then please suggest me the right approach.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I am not 100% sure if it is possible to create one purely in SwiftUI. I would suggest starting by creating one in UIKit so that you have a handle on how they work. Here is a tutorial on how to do it in UIKit https://www.raywenderlich.com/49-custom-keyboard-extensions-getting-started. My understanding for Keyboard Extensions is that the code for them must be contained within the extension that you have created.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for replying. So, my approach is not right I think. What if I use this approach :-> I should design keyboard buttons using swiftui and then call it in Inputviewcontroller using UIHostingController. ?? I am still confuse. Please tell me.

Comment: That may work. But as I said you probably want to give it a go on UIKit first so that you understand how to create a custom keyboard extension and then see what you can change to work with SwiftUI once you gave done that.

Comment: @Andrew ... umm ok then let me experiment a bit and I will update my question soon to tell what I got.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my approach using `UIHostingController`:

When I added a new target "Keyboard" of keyboard extension, XCode automatically generated a class `KeyboardViewController`:

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
    // some code
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.nextKeyboardButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        // some code
    }
    // some code
}
```

I added the view through `UIHostingController` with my keyboard view as the `rootView` of it. Then added it and its view as children of `KeyboardViewController` and the view of `KeyboardViewController`:

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
    // some code
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: KeyboardView(viewController: self))
        view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        addChild(hostingController)

        self.nextKeyboardButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        // some code
    }
    // some code
}
```

And my `KeyboardView` was like:

```
struct KeyboardView: View {
    var viewController: KeyboardViewController
    var body: some View {
        // some view as you designed
    }
}
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I initially expected the containing UIHostingController's view to be set to something like auto-resizing constraints, but, it seems that I needed to add a line stating: hostingController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

If there's another preferred way to set the size constraints anyone who comes across this feel free to share.

Comment: & how did you handle the PreviewProvider in KeyboardView?